# Hive query too slow and failed

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, tez

I've execute a "group by" query in Hive txt table

```
select day,count(*) from mts_order where source="MTS_REG_ORDER" group by day;
```

but it shows:

```
    Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex re-running, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1496722904961_13822_1_00Vertex re-running, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1496722904961_13822_1_00Vertex failed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1496722904961_13822_1_01, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1496722904961_13822_1_01_000222, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in Fetcher_O {Map_1} #0
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:303)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:285)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map_1: Shuffle failed with too many fetch failures and insufficient progress!failureCounts=1, pendingInputs=1, fetcherHealthy=false, reducerProgressedEnough=true, reducerStalled=true
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.isShuffleHealthy(ShuffleScheduler.java:1015)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.copyFailed(ShuffleScheduler.java:756)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.copyFromHost(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:313)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.fetchNext(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:178)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:191)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:54)
    ... 5 more
, errorMessage=Shuffle Runner Failed:org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in Fetcher_O {Map_1} #0
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:303)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:285)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map_1: Shuffle failed with too many fetch failures and insufficient progress!failureCounts=1, pendingInputs=1, fetcherHealthy=false, reducerProgressedEnough=true, reducerStalled=true
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.isShuffleHealthy(ShuffleScheduler.java:1015)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.copyFailed(ShuffleScheduler.java:756)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.copyFromHost(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:313)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.fetchNext(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:178)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:191)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:54)
    ... 5 more
], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in Fetcher_O {Map_1} #0
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:303)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:285)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map_1: Shuffle failed with too many fetch failures and insufficient progress!failureCounts=1, pendingInputs=1, fetcherHealthy=false, reducerProgressedEnough=true, reducerStalled=true
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.isShuffleHealthy(ShuffleScheduler.java:1015)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.copyFailed(ShuffleScheduler.java:756)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.copyFromHost(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:313)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.fetchNext(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:178)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:191)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:54)
    ... 5 more
, errorMessage=Shuffle Runner Failed:org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in Fetcher_O {Map_1} #0
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:303)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:285)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map_1: Shuffle failed with too many fetch failures and insufficient progress!failureCounts=1, pendingInputs=1, fetcherHealthy=false, reducerProgressedEnough=true, reducerStalled=true
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.isShuffleHealthy(ShuffleScheduler.java:1015)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.copyFailed(ShuffleScheduler.java:756)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.copyFromHost(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:313)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.fetchNext(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:178)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:191)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:54)
    ... 5 more
], TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in Fetcher_O {Map_1} #0
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:303)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:285)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map_1: Shuffle failed with too many fetch failures and insufficient progress!failureCounts=1, pendingInputs=1, fetcherHealthy=false, reducerProgressedEnough=true, reducerStalled=true
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.isShuffleHealthy(ShuffleScheduler.java:1015)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.copyFailed(ShuffleScheduler.java:756)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.copyFromHost(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:313)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.fetchNext(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:178)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:191)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:54)
    ... 5 more
, errorMessage=Shuffle Runner Failed:org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in Fetcher_O {Map_1} #0
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:303)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:285)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map_1: Shuffle failed with too many fetch failures and insufficient progress!failureCounts=1, pendingInputs=1, fetcherHealthy=false, reducerProgressedEnough=true, reducerStalled=true
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.isShuffleHealthy(ShuffleScheduler.java:1015)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.copyFailed(ShuffleScheduler.java:756)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.copyFromHost(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:313)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.fetchNext(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:178)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:191)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:54)
    ... 5 more
], TaskAttempt 3 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in Fetcher_O {Map_1} #0
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:303)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:285)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map_1: Shuffle failed with too many fetch failures and insufficient progress!failureCounts=1, pendingInputs=1, fetcherHealthy=false, reducerProgressedEnough=true, reducerStalled=true
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.isShuffleHealthy(ShuffleScheduler.java:1015)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.copyFailed(ShuffleScheduler.java:756)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.copyFromHost(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:313)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.fetchNext(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:178)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:191)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:54)
    ... 5 more
, errorMessage=Shuffle Runner Failed:org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in Fetcher_O {Map_1} #0
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:303)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.Shuffle$RunShuffleCallable.callInternal(Shuffle.java:285)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map_1: Shuffle failed with too many fetch failures and insufficient progress!failureCounts=1, pendingInputs=1, fetcherHealthy=false, reducerProgressedEnough=true, reducerStalled=true
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.isShuffleHealthy(ShuffleScheduler.java:1015)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.ShuffleScheduler.copyFailed(ShuffleScheduler.java:756)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.copyFromHost(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:313)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.fetchNext(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:178)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:191)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.common.shuffle.orderedgrouped.FetcherOrderedGrouped.callInternal(FetcherOrderedGrouped.java:54)
    ... 5 more
]], Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:26, Vertex vertex_1496722904961_13822_1_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:0 (state=08S01,code=2)
```

It seems like a timeout error. The full hadoop job log is here: [job.log](http://www.filedropper.com/hive)

How can I solve the problem?

---

updated, I've found that the reason why the query can not be finished is because the NodeManager is dead, I post the detail info in the post [Hadoop NodeManager exit without log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800619/hadoop-nodemanager-exit-without-log), please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Did you try to run the exact same query with MapReduce instead of Tez? Because MR is slower but sometimes more robust; and an MR stack trace is much simpler to analyze...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Not yet, will try it later, thanks

Comment: Which version of hadoop and hive you are using? Windows or Linux? As @SamsonScharfrichter asked, Did you tried with MR mode?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I've tried that but it seems the problem is related to the nodemanager, please see my update.

Comment: @Kumar thanks and please see my update

Answer (score 1):

did you take a look to this?

["Too many fetch-failures" while using Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181248/too-many-fetch-failures-while-using-hive)

That helped me to solve an issue like this before. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

When you use group by clause then take only one indexed field. It will help yopu to get faster result like describe below.

**Step 1**

Add Index in `source` field

**Step : 2**

```
select day,count(id) from mts_order where source="MTS_REG_ORDER" group by day;
```

I hope this will resolve your issue.